# Inner Join - Allocate Vector in R

Tags: r, compiler-errors

I'm trying to do an inner_join between two tables by a common column "codigo_estado". However it is giving an error of "allocate vector of size 1,4 gb".

Code:
[image]

```
arquivo_antigo_filtrado<- arquivo_antigo %>% select(codigo_estado,PV, PP, PSD, PSCF)
colnames(arquivo_antigo_filtrado) = c("codigo_estado","pv_antigo", "pp_antigo", "psd_antigo", "pscf_antigo")
arquivo_atual_validado<-inner_join(arquivo_atual,arquivo_antigo_filtrado,by="codigo_estado")
```

Dataset:

[image]

Error:

[image]

Comment: Please post texts instead of images. Also are you sure the inner join is the safest thing to do? Are you not looking for a cbind or something??? I see both your data has 16092 rows.

Comment: yes, it is not always the same amount. I put the code.

Comment: The error message indicate that you are out of memory. That the computation is to heavy for your machine. So either try an other join-method or try it on a machine with more RAM. You could also try a package that is more memory efficient, such as data.table.

Comment: It is running on my server, it has 32 GB of ham. Do you have any idea how I can join the tables without the interior?